# Terraform Azure: How to use multiple version of the AzureRM provider?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We have been using older versions of azurerm provider("~> 3.0.2") however to provision the "azurerm_private_dns_resolver" we need a new azurerm provider("~> 3.30.2").

The below terraform code throws the following error

> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azurerm: no available releases match the given constraints ~> 3.0.2, ~> 3.30.0

```
# Azure Provider source and version being used
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.30.0"
    }  
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 3.0.2"

  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "latest"
  version = "~> 3.30.0"

  features {}
}


module "az-resource-group" {
  source = "./modules/resource_group/"

  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.latest
  }

  az_rg_name     = "example-resources"
  az_rg_location = "Central US"
}
```

**Update:** As mentioned, I tried to break the providers into module

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Resource Group Module:**

[image]

[image]

Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, it is not possible to use the same provider with multiple versions in the same codebase. You can resolve this by having two options.

- Separating the new resource which requires a new provider in another directory or any logical way which should have a dedicated/explicit provider config and state file. (not recommended as the code will be redundant)

##### Example directory structure.

```bash
.
├── .terraform
│   └── providers
│       └── registry.terraform.io
│           └── hashicorp
│               └── azurerm
│                   └── 3.0.2
│                       └── darwin_amd64
│                           └── terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.2_x5
├── .terraform.lock.hcl
├── latest_provider_directory
│   ├── .terraform
│   │   └── providers
│   │       └── registry.terraform.io
│   │           └── hashicorp
│   │               └── azurerm
│   │                   └── 3.32.0
│   │                       └── darwin_amd64
│   │                           └── terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.32.0_x5
│   ├── .terraform.lock.hcl
│   ├── providers.tf
│   └── new_resource.tf
├── providers.tf
└── old_resource.tf
```

##### Provider config or `providers.tf`

```
## provider config supports old versions.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"

    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
# Configure the Microsoft Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

## provider config supports new versions in latest_provider_directory to support resources with new provider versions.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.32.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

- Upgrading the current terraform code to the newest terraform-provider-azurerm provider. Usually, terraform-provider-azurerm does support backward compatibility but in some edge cases, it is possible that some arguments are deprecated or even modified. (recommended)

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.32.0" ## upgrading means updating this version from current to new(required) version.
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

**Note**: Kindly init and run a plan on your existing code with the new provider version once you upgrade it and verifies that you get the below message either locally or done in pipelines.

```bash
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

Also going through [azurerm-terraform-provider-Changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) would be good to get more insights.

As a side note *Version constraints inside provider configuration blocks are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Terraform*

> Tested this warning with terraform version `1.3.5`

Your new update module has an explicit provider config, which means that this module can only be used with the mentioned config. which can be a bit more flexible either by removing the provider config or to support multiple versions for both terraform and provider.

Use this Directory structure for your current state:

```bash
.
├── latest_provider_terraform_files_directory
│   ├── providers.tf
│   └── resource_group.tf
├── modules
│   └── resource_group.tf
└── old_provider_terraform_files_directory
    ├── providers.tf
    └── resource_group.tf
```

Detailed directory structure:

```bash
.
├── latest_provider_terraform_files_directory
│   ├── .terraform
│   │   ├── modules
│   │   │   └── modules.json
│   │   └── providers
│   │       └── registry.terraform.io
│   │           └── hashicorp
│   │               └── azurerm
│   │                   └── 3.32.0
│   │                       └── darwin_amd64
│   │                           └── terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.32.0_x5
│   ├── .terraform.lock.hcl
│   ├── providers.tf
│   └── resource_group.tf
├── modules
│   └── resource_group.tf
└── old_provider_terraform_files_directory
    ├── .terraform
    │   ├── modules
    │   │   └── modules.json
    │   └── providers
    │       └── registry.terraform.io
    │           └── hashicorp
    │               └── azurerm
    │                   └── 3.0.2
    │                       └── darwin_amd64
    │                           └── terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.2_x5
    ├── .terraform.lock.hcl
    ├── providers.tf
    └── resource_group.tf
```

Comment: Ishan Sharma, I have updated the question. Can you have a look and suggest?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar I have updated my answer as per your current question, don't get confused with the module provider config. Currently, your module only supports root modules with the same provider config.

Comment: Would it be possible for you share a git repo sample? Thank you, Ishan Sharma.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar please refer to this repository : https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/azure/multiple_versions_of_terraform_provider 
let me know if you need any further help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the alias feature to get around this
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#provider-aliases-within-modules

will look something like below where you pass the right alias to the module

```
provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "old"
  version = "~> 3.0.2"

  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "latest"
  version = "~> 3.30.0"

  features {}
}

module "az-resource-group" {
  source = "./modules/resource_group/"

  //Pass your preferred provider here
  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.latest
  }

  az_rg_name     = "example-resources"
  az_rg_location = "Central US"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work